# Найти итем в ItemsControl WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

Имеется `ItemsControl`, который выводит список `radiobutton` и `textblock`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemImages" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImageModel}">
              <StackPanel>
                   <RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonImageModel}" GroupName="1">
                   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Path}" Width="64"/>
                   </RadioButton>
                   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Каким образом я могу отследить выбранный `radiobutton` в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если использование `ItemsControl` не принципиально, то просто используйте `ListBox` с таким же переопределением шаблона для данных. В `RadioButton` используйте привязку `IsChecked` к `IsSelected`  `ListBoxItem`-a:

```
<ListBox x:Name="itemImages" Grid.Row="1" SelectedItem={Binding <!--здесь будет ваш выбранный объект -->}>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <WrapPanel/>
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ImageModel}">
              <StackPanel>
                   <RadioButton Style="{DynamicResource RadioButtonImageModel}" GroupName="1" 
                            IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Path=IsSelected}">
                   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Path}" Width="64"/>
                   </RadioButton>
                   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
              </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```